# Insert data ro a JSONObject in some format

Tags: java, json

How to insert/add data to a JSONObject
am trying to create a JSONObject that contains following set of data.

```
 {
     "feature": "testFeature",
     "scenario": [{
         "name": "Add numbers",
         "tag": "@test"
     }, {
         "name": "Delete numbers",
         "tag": "@test123"
     }]

 }
```

i dont know how to proceed.please help.

```
   Collection<JSONObject> items = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
   JSONArray array1 = new JSONArray();
   JSONObject item1 = new JSONObject();
   item1.put("scenario", array1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
JSONObject main = new JSONObject();
main.put("feature","testFeature");
JSONArray scenario = new JSONArray();
JSONObject s1 = new JSONObject();
s1.put("name","Add numbers");
s1.put("tags","@test");
JSONObject s2 = new JSONObject();
s2.put("name","Delete numbers");
s2.put("tags","@test123");
scenario.add(s1);
scenario.add(s2);
main.put("scenario", scenario);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package demo;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONArray;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("feature", "testFeature");
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jsonArray_json1 = new JSONObject();
        jsonArray_json1.put("name", "Add numbers");
        jsonArray_json1.put("tag", "@test");
        jsonArray.add(jsonArray_json1);
        JSONObject jsonArray_json2 = new JSONObject();
        jsonArray_json2.put("name", "Delete numbers");
        jsonArray_json2.put("tag", "@test123");
        jsonArray.add(jsonArray_json2);
        json.put("scenario", jsonArray);
        System.out.println(json);

    }
}
```